# Shiny radioButton switching between different calculations, using with datatable

Tags: r, rstudio, shiny

I wanted to make a small Shiny app, but I got stuck on the very first step, because I think I've taken too big of a bite for an unexeperienced coder.

What I want the app's following lines to do is to: Using data.table package, do one of the two calculations, average wages or sum them, but only for the state which got selected with selectizeInput.
 The error I'm getting is:
 "Warning in eventReactiveHandler(...) : NAs introduced by coercion"
I googled a lot to get to this point, but I couldn't find anything to help me futhermore.

```
    library(shiny)
    library(data.table)
    ui <- fluidPage(
      selectizeInput(inputId = "Stat", "Choose a state", choices = unique(data4$STATE)),
      radioButtons("calRB", "Choose calculation", c("sum", "avg")),
      verbatimTextOutput("rslt"),
      actionButton("count", "Go")
    )
    server <- function(input, output) {
      Rslt <- eventReactive({input$count, switch(as.numeric(input$calRB),
 return(data.table(data4)[STATE == input$Stat, sum(A00200)]),
 return(data.table(data4)[STATE == input$Stat, mean(A00200)]})))
      output$rslt <- renderPrint(Rslt())
    }
    shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I'm working on a single line for way too long, usually I work stuff out. This code is fairly similiar to one I found here.

Help / Education much appreciated, cheers! Pavel.

Comment: can you also provide `data4`

Comment: The answare from HubertL worked. The table and the column should be fine since I worked with them previously. Thanks tho!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is your trying to transform text into numbers which yields into creating NAs.

Check the syntax for `swicth`

This code would work:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput(inputId = "Stat", "Choose a state", choices = unique(data4$STATE)),
  radioButtons("calRB", "Choose calculation", c("sum", "avg")),
  verbatimTextOutput("rslt"),
  actionButton("count", "Go")
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  Rslt <- eventReactive(input$count,{ 
    switch(input$calRB,
           sum=return(data.table(data4)[STATE == input$Stat, sum(A00200)]),
           avg=return(data.table(data4)[STATE == input$Stat, mean(A00200)]))})
  output$rslt <- renderPrint(Rslt())
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Yes, I have difficulties with when to use switch. this works, exactly as I wanted, thank you so much